# Why is the form not updating when I select a new sector from the list?

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

Im trying to fix a form on http://s195004125.websitehome.co.uk/jobs/
for some reason the sector selection box doesnt update the list below when a change ios made but it changes when you select a different location, I have modified the sector filter to include these sections:

```
<select id="sector" name="search_categories" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $categories ); ?>">>
    <option value="">-- Please Select Sector --</option>
    <option value="Building, Maintenance &amp; Construction">Building, Maintenance &amp; Construction</option>
    <option value="Care &amp; Support">Care &amp; Support</option>
    <option value="Housing">Housing</option>
    <option value="Public Sector &amp; Not for Profit">Public Sector &amp; Not for Profit</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $pull_sector; ?>"><?php echo $pull_sector; ?></option>
</select>
```

and the ajax for this is

```
if ( $search_categories ) {
        $showing_categories = array();

        foreach ( $search_categories as $category ) {
            $category_object = get_term_by( is_numeric( $category ) ? 'id' : 'slug', $category, 'job_listing_category' );

            if ( ! is_wp_error( $category_object ) ) {
                $showing_categories[] = $category_object->name;
            }
        }

        $result['showing'][] = implode( ', ', $showing_categories );
    }
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did the answer below answer this question for you?

Comment: Not quite, realized I had to add my input to the selector class in my JS script that handles the jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like only your locations drop-down is triggering the ajax query. I believe the issue is that the javascript is listing for a change event on these elements: `'#search_keywords, #search_location, .job_types :input, #search_categories, .job-manager-filter'` in the code below (line 178 in http://s195004125.websitehome.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/wp-job-manager/assets/js/ajax-filters.js?ver=1.23.13)

```
$( '#search_keywords, #search_location, .job_types :input, #search_categories, .job-manager-filter' ).change( function() {
    var target   = $( this ).closest( 'div.job_listings' );
    target.triggerHandler( 'update_results', [ 1, false ] );
    job_manager_store_state( target, 1 );
} )
```

But, the actual id of the element is `sector`, not `search_categories` - perhaps try adding '#sector' to the elements listed, so that the javascript is listening for its change event too.